# Avast is automatically attaching its advertisement to every email sent from the computer

Tags: email, anti-virus, avast

I don't know how to get rid of this behaviour of avast. It is attaching it's promotion to each and every email sent through my computer. **I am using free version**.

[image: see this screen shot of the email sent]

And the worst part is that I get to know about this after the email has been sent to the other person. At the time of composing mail, its not showing anything to me regarding this.

When I open my sent-box to check the sent mail, there I get to know that something extra has been sent in my each and every email. Why this antivirus is behaving like a virus itself? It's very dangerous for an important mail. Please help me how to get rid of this attachment.

Comment: Avast has a [forum](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?action=search2) with info on why they not allow to do this.

Comment: @Luuk You are allowed to turn this off. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I don't know how to get rid of this behaviour of avast.

> **To enable or disable Avast Email Signature, follow these steps**:
>
> [image]

Make sure you **uncheck** "Add a signature to the end of sent emails".

Screen shot from my Avast Free:

[image]

Source [Avast Email Signatures](https://www.avast.com/lp-email-signatures)